# Calculating SpO2 using pulse sensor

Tags: arduino-uno

I was wondering is there a way to calculate SpO2 using a pulse sensor?
I calculated BPM and stress before with pulse sensor and now I want to calculate SpO2.

Link to Pulse sensor [manual](https://www.generationrobots.com/media/DetecteurDePoulsAmplifie/PulseSensorAmpedGettingStartedGuide.pdf)

Comment: That depends on the pulse sensor. For measuring SpO2 you need a sensor with 2 different LED with different light wavelengths. What sensor do you use?

Comment: @chrisl well its a Biometric Pulse Rate or Heart Rate detecting sensor . check out the link : https://www.generationrobots.com/media/DetecteurDePoulsAmplifie/PulseSensorAmpedGettingStartedGuide.pdf

Answer (score 2):

For measuring oxygen saturation (SpO2) with a pulse sensor, you need to use the fact, that hemoglobin, that carries oxygen, will reflect in different light wave lengths, as hemoglobin, which doesn't carry oxygen. But that also means, that you need to use light in at least 2 different wavelengths. Common are one red (about 660nm)(though green may also work) and infrared (about 940nm). When lighted sequentially with both LEDs, you can measure the refection of both parts and calculate the ratio between them (SpO2).

But your sensor only has 1 LED, which is green. So you cannot measure SpO2 with this sensor. You need one fitting the above description.